# Print each function with #### around them

Tags: python, function

I have several functions printing out lots of text.

How can I print them out so each has a ##### line separating them:

```
def a():
print('1')

def b():
    print('2')

def call():
    a()
    b()


>>call
>>1
  2

but so it's like this:
>>########################
    1
  ########################
  ########################
    2
  ########################
```

Comment: Without modifying `a`, `b`, or `call`? You don't.

Comment: python tutorial please

Comment: Make a new function called "PrintWithHashes" which prints hashes, then the value it is sent, then more hashes. Then replace print() with PrintWithHashes()

Comment: @JeffUK That puts hashes between each line of output, not between the output of each *function*.

Comment: @chepner it's a silly question, until OP tells us what they tried and why it doesn't work. My solution would give the desired output as described, assuming that they only print one line per function, which they are currently.

Comment: I mean what should I put inside each of the print statements to return ######### with said text inside

Comment: What's wrong with print('###############') ?

Comment: All I want to do is separate the different text output

Comment: @chepner You can i think? how about modifying `print`, i.e. setting `end= '\n########################\n'` (not recommending this of course)

Comment: That would modify *every* print; I'm assuming in general that each of the functions called by `call` might output more than one line of output.

Comment: Sorted, thanks for the help peeps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) and do something like this:

```
def hashDecor(some_func):
    def wrapper():
        print '#######'
        some_func()
        print '#######'
    return wrapper

@hashDecor
def a():
    print('1')

@hashDecor
def b():
    print('2')

def call():
    a()
    b()

call()
########
#1
########
########
#2
########
```

Comment: please don't encourage low effort posts.